# I can not figure out why TextGlowDemo no longer functions in ios7

Tags: ios, ios7, uilabel, quartz-core, glow

I am working on a project that utilizes code from this GitHub app, `TextGlowDemo`. The app basically uses the QuartzCore Framework to add a drop-shadow to a uilabel by overriding drawTextInRect and adding `CGContextSetShadow` and `CGContextSetShadowWithColor` to make the drop shadow look like glowing text. The program works perfectly in ios 6, but in ios7 the glow mysteriously disappears. I do not get any warnings about deprecated methods so I do not know what is going on, any ideas?

Entire project can be found here:
https://github.com/andrewgleave/TextGlowDemo

here is the code that draws the glow

```
- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    CGContextSetShadow(context, self.glowOffset, self.glowAmount);
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, self.glowOffset, self.glowAmount, glowColorRef);

    [super drawTextInRect:rect];

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the latest IOS upgrade fixed this problem. It started working before I had the opportunity to try Brett's solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your self.glowOffset is probably CGSizeZero.  I am not sure why, but in iOS7 you don't see a shadow with an offset with CGMakeSize(0.0f, 0.0f).